# Sort a data frame based on another sorted column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame that is sorted based on one column(numeric column) to assign the rank. if this column value is zero then arrange the data frame based on another character column for those rows which have zero as a value in a numeric column.

But to give rank I have to consider var2 that is the reason I sorted based on var2, if there is any identical values in var2 for those rows I have to consider var3 to give rank. please see the data frame 2 and 3 rows, var2 values are identical in that case i have to consider var3 to give rank. In case var2 is zero i have to sort the var1 column(character column) in alphabetical order and give rank. if var2 is NA no rank. please refer the data frame given below.

Below, the data frame is sorted based on var2 column descending order, but var2 contains zero also if var2 is zero I have to sort the data frame based on var1 for the rows which are having zero in var2. I need sort by var1 for those rows which are having var2 as zero and followed by NA in alphabetical order of var1.

```
    example:
    #      var1    var2    var3    rank
    # 1     c      556      45       1
    # 2     a      345      35       3
    # 3     f      345      64       2
    # 4     b      134      87       4
    # 5     z       0       34       5
    # 6     d       0       32       6
    # 7     c       0       12       7
    # 8     a       0       23       8
    # 9     e      NA      
    # 10    b      NA       

below is my code 
df <- data.frame(var1=c("c","a","f","b","z","d", "c","a", "e", "b", "ad", "gf", "kg", "ts", "mp"), var2=c(134, NA,345, 200, 556,NA, 345, 200, 150, 0, 25,10,0,150,0), var3=c(65,'',45,34,68,'',73,12,35,23,34,56,56,78,123))

# To break the tie between var3 and var2 
orderdf <- df[order(df$var2, df$var1, decreasing = TRUE), ] 

#assigning rank 
rankdf <- orderdf %>% mutate(rank = ifelse(is.na(var2),'', seq(1:nrow(orderdf))))
```

expected output is sort the var1 in alphabetical order if var2 value is zero(for those rows with var2 value is zero)

```
    expected output:
    #      var1    var2    var3    rank
    # 1     c      556      45       1
    # 2     a      345      35       3
    # 3     f      345      64       2
    # 4     b      134      87       4
    # 5     a       0       34       5
    # 6     c       0       32       6
    # 7     d       0       12       7
    # 8     z       0       23       8
    # 9     b      NA      
    # 10    e      NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use

```
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(var2), var1)
```

and afterwards you create the column `rank`

---

#### EDIT

The following code is a bit cumbersome but it gets the job done. Basically it orders the rows in which `var2` is equal or different from zero separately, then combines the two ordered dataframes together and finally creates the `rank` column.

Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c("c","a","f","b","z","d", "c","a", "e", "z", "ad", "gf", "kg", "ts", "mp"), 
  var2 = c(134, NA,345, 200, 556,NA, 345, 200, 150, 0, 25,10,0,150,0), 
  var3 = as.numeric(c(65,'',45,34,68,'',73,12,35,23,34,56,56,78,123))
)
df
#    var1 var2 var3
# 1     c  134   65
# 2     a   NA   NA
# 3     f  345   45
# 4     b  200   34
# 5     z  556   68
# 6     d   NA   NA
# 7     c  345   73
# 8     a  200   12
# 9     e  150   35
# 10    z    0   23
# 11   ad   25   34
# 12   gf   10   56
# 13   kg    0   56
# 14   ts  150   78
# 15   mp    0  123
```

Code

```
df %>% 
# work on rows with var2 different from 0 or NA
  filter(var2 != 0) %>% 
  arrange(desc(var2), desc(var3)) %>% 
# merge with rows with var2 equal to 0 or NA
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(var2 == 0 | is.na(var2)) %>% arrange(var1)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(var2)) %>% 
# create the rank column only for the rows with var2 different from NA
  mutate(
    rank = seq_len(nrow(df)),
    rank = ifelse(is.na(var2), NA, rank)
    )
```

Output

```
#    var1 var2 var3 rank
# 1     z  556   68    1
# 2     c  345   73    2
# 3     f  345   45    3
# 4     b  200   34    4
# 5     a  200   12    5
# 6    ts  150   78    6
# 7     e  150   35    7
# 8     c  134   65    8
# 9    ad   25   34    9
# 10   gf   10   56   10
# 11   kg    0   56   11
# 12   mp    0  123   12
# 13    z    0   23   13
# 14    a   NA   NA   NA
# 15    d   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: thanks for you answer.  I have changed my question , can you  please provide your suggestion on changed requirement.

Comment: @Hmm I've edited my answer, please check it out and tell me if this is what you want to obtain

Comment: Thank you, but if you see row number 4,5 in your output, var2 has identical(same) values in that case I have to consider var3 to give rank. In this case row 5 should be ranked 4 and row 4 should be ranked 5. If you run my code I am getting result based on that but the sorting for zeros values not happening.

Comment: I've edited my answer, so now the `rank` of rows 4 & 5 are inverted (as well for the couple of rows 2 & 3, 6 & 7)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in base R, using `order` :

```
cols <- c('var1', 'var2')
remaining_cols <- setdiff(names(df), cols)
df1 <- df[cols]
cbind(transform(df1[with(df1, order(-var2, var1)), ], 
                rank = seq_len(nrow(df1))), df[remaining_cols])


#   var1 var2 rank var3
#1     c  556    1   45
#2     a  345    2   35
#3     f  345    3   64
#4     b  134    4   87
#8     a    0    5   34
#7     c    0    6   32
#6     d    0    7   12
#5     z    0    8   23
#10    b   NA    9   10
#9     e   NA   10   11
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "z"), class = "factor"), 
var2 = c(556L, 345L, 345L, 134L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA), 
var3 = c(45L, 35L, 64L, 87L, 34L, 32L, 12L, 23L, 10L, 11L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: thanks for you answer.  I have changed my question , can you  please provide your suggestion on changed requirement.

Comment: @Hmm I have updated the answer,  please have a look. It would be better if you provide a complete reproducible example with `dput` as I have provided at the end of my answer. It makes it easier to copy the data and help you.

Comment: In case of identical values of var2, we have to consider var3 to give rank. if you see rank for row no. 2 and 3  considered var3 value to give rank.
below logic i am using for identical values, but on top of that i have to sort var1 if var2 values are zero.
df[order(df$var2, df$var1, decreasing = TRUE), ]

Comment: Why there is no value for `var3` for row 9 and 10?

Comment: var3 value is not available then var2 value will be NA and there will be no rank for that

Comment: I have given the code that I am using, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Using only base R's `order()` function, sort first on descending order of `var2` then ascending order of `var1` to sort the data by passing the subsequent integer vector to square braces

```
df[order(-df$var2, df$var1), ]
```

Adding a rank column too is then just

```
df[order(-df$var2, df$var1), "rank"] <- 1:length(df$var1)
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have changed my question , can you please provide your suggestion on changed requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-var2, var1)][, rank := seq_len(.N)][]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "z"), class = "factor"), 
var2 = c(1456L, 456L, 345L, 134L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have changed my question , can you please provide your suggestion on changed requirement.